# PHP get images in folder returns same image

Tags: php, arrays, joomla

I am creating a joomla module that pulls in a article and then assigns a image to it out of a folder (no specific order).

But it keeps returning the same image :/... Everything else works perfectly i just need it to grab a different image out of the folder for each article.

Here's the mod_slider.php(including only essentials):

```
$a = explode(",", $params->get('id'));

foreach ($a as $k => $val) {
    $args = $val;
    $item[] = ModArticleSlider::getArticles($args,$params);
}
```

and the helper.php(includes the entire class):

```
class ModArticleSlider {
    public static function getArticles($args,$params){
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $id = $args;
        if($id > 0){

            $query  = "select * ";
            $query .= "FROM #__content  WHERE id =".$id." AND state=1 " ;

            //echo $query;
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $item = $db->loadObject();
        }


        $folder = $params->get('folder');

        if(JString::strpos($folder, JURI::base()) === 0)
        {
            $folder = str_replace(JURI::base(), '', $folder);
        }

        if(JString::strpos($folder, JPATH_SITE) === 0)
        {
            $folder = str_replace(JPATH_BASE, '', $folder);
        }

        $folder = str_replace('\\', '/', $folder);

        $dir = JPATH_BASE.'/'.$folder;
        $files = array();

        if(is_dir($dir))
        {
            if($handle = opendir($dir))
            {
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== false)
                {
                    if($file != '.' AND $file != '..' AND $file != 'index.html')
                    {
                        $files[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            }

            closedir($handle);

            $types = array_map('trim', explode(',', $params->get('type')));
            $images = array();

            foreach($files as $img){

                if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$img))
                {
                    foreach($types as $type)
                    {
                        $muster = '@'.$type.'$@i';

                        if(preg_match($muster, $img))
                        {
                            $item->name = $img;
                            $item->folder = str_replace('\\', '/', $folder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $item;
    }

}
```

and then the index.php(including only essentials):

```
<?php foreach ($item as $items):?>
<img src="<?php echo $items->folder.'/'.$items->name ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: The way you are assigning the numbers to the variable `$a` is wrong.

You should assign an array to that variable, like so `$a = array(1,2,3,4);`.

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Done any debugging? Checked what the arguments are? Checked what you're generating for paths? Checked what you're finding in those generated paths?

Comment: I really am still a beginner.. Ive been trying to do what i can. . .

Comment: @Shef that's my error $a= 1,2,3,4; was never in the code...

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven Start debugging your issues slowly as @MarcB has suggested. Check exactly is `$params->get('id')` returning?

Comment: i have.. it returns Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 38 [2] => 8 [3] => 4 [4] => 36 ) look everything works it pulls in the articles based on ids that it gets from $params->get('id'). the only problem is it returns the same image for every article.. it doesn't grab any other images.. the goal is to have a different image with each article..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't actually selecting a random image. The code I'm looking at is this section:

```
        $types = array_map('trim', explode(',', $params->get('type')));
        $images = array();

        foreach($files as $img){

            if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$img))
            {
                foreach($types as $type)
                {
                    $muster = '@'.$type.'$@i';

                    if(preg_match($muster, $img))
                    {
                        $item->name = $img;
                        $item->folder = str_replace('\\', '/', $folder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You loop through all the files, but if it matches, you are just assigning them over each other. `$item->name` and `$item->folder` are overwritten each time. I also don't see where you are actually randomizing the file list, so you can't really expect a random image. (I''m assuming you were probably going to use `$images` for something to make the randomization happen or get all matches, so you probably can delete it.) I would add a `shuffle` on $files to randomize the file list and then break the loop after you get your first match to avoid processing the entire list unnecessarily:

```
        $types = array_map('trim', explode(',', $params->get('type')));
        shuffle($files);

        foreach($files as $img){

            if(!is_dir($dir.'/'.$img))
            {
                foreach($types as $type)
                {
                    $muster = '@'.$type.'$@i';

                    if(preg_match($muster, $img))
                    {
                        $item->name = $img;
                        $item->folder = str_replace('\\', '/', $folder);
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey seems to be working great.. Thank you.. just one thing.. it assigns the same image to some articles... any fix for that.. so that it only display the image once?

Comment: To handle that case, you would want to set `$files` to be a static variable, only build the list once and then just keep using it from then on (and only randomize it once), and probably unset the item when it matches from the array so that it won't match on the next run.